# Facebook Graph Api AppRequests 'Dont ask again before sending...'

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I am having some difficulty implementing an apprequest into my Facebook Canvas game. I currently have the apprequests working fine, except everytime I send an appreqeust, a popup appears with Facebook API with a preview, the code is fired exactly the same as their docs :

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Please send me backup',
    to: id
}, function(response){
    // deal with response
});
```

My popup looks like this:

[image]

However, I wish to make the popup include the option to have the checkbox "don't ask again before sending requests to ... "

This popup looks like this:

[image]

I have tried all all variations of code I could find on google, but to no avail.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has this problem again, I Solved it using frictionlessRequests. It isn't possible to  change this on the fly, but when you initialise the Facebook API.

You can do so by using:

```
FB.init({
appId  : APP_ID,
oauth  : true,
frictionlessRequests : true
});
```

More information can be found here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#advancedtopics